# Count of rows affected by SELECT INTO query with Microsoft JDBC driver

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

Is there a way to get a "rows affected" result for

```sql
SELECT * INTO TableB FROM TableA
```

with Microsoft's JDBC driver for SQL Server? When I execute that query in SQL Server Management Studio it returns the number of rows the same way as it does for DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE.

I tried `executeQuery` but it doesn't return a `ResultSet`. I tried `executeUpdate` but I always get `-1` as result, and I tried `execute`, but the return value seems to be `false` so there is no `ResultSet`.
I've downloaded the MS JDBC driver 6.0 from 31.01.2017 because I read about problems with older versions.

Comment: Wouldn't `SELECT * FROM TableA` give you the resultset you need ? It's going to contain exactly all the rows your `SELECT INTO` has inserted into `TableB`. You can also enclose the two in a transaction, if you know that `TableA` might be modified externally.

Comment: Using `executeUpdate` would be the correct approach. The MS JDBC driver is notoriously low quality, so it may be the driver's fault that you're getting `-1` back always. You might want to try if using the [jtDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) driver gives you better results.

Comment: ok thx, then it's like i thought and the ms jdbc cuases the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update: This issue has been fixed in [version 6.1.5](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/releases/tag/v6.1.5) of the JDBC Driver for SQL Server.

---

*(previous answer)*

Testing confirms that even with the most recent Microsoft JDBC driver (6.0.8112.100)

```java
sql = "SELECT * INTO TableB FROM TableA";
try (Statement st = conn.createStatement()) {
    int n = st.executeUpdate(sql);
    System.out.printf("%d row(s) affected", n);
}
```

produces

```
-1 row(s) affected
```

while the jTDS driver correctly returns the actual number of rows:

```
3 row(s) affected
```

A workaround for the Microsoft JDBC driver would be to use an anonymous code block to return a ResultSet containing `@@ROWCOUNT`

```java
sql = 
        "SET NOCOUNT ON; " +
        "SELECT * INTO TableB FROM TableA; " +
        "SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS n; ";
try (
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql)) {
    rs.next();
    int n = rs.getInt(1);
    System.out.printf("%d row(s) affected", n);
}
```

which does correctly return

```
3 row(s) affected
```